# INSERT INTO SQL syntax error in vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, syntax-error, sql-insert

I have gone through this with a fine tooth comb and can't locate the syntax error, I've tested it in access and it works perfectly, can anyone see the error?

```
Dim Day As String = CmbDay.Text
Dim Time As String = TxtTime.Text
Dim Club As String = TxtClub.Text
Dim Room As String = TxtRoom.Text
Dim Requirement As String = TxtRequire.Text
Dim order As String = "0"

If Day = "Monday" Then
    order = "1"
ElseIf Day = "Tuesday" Then
    order = "2"
ElseIf Day = "Wednesday" Then
    order = "3"
ElseIf Day = "Thursday" Then
    order = "4"
ElseIf Day = "Friday" Then
    order = "5"
End If


Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Clubs (Daysort, ClubName, Times, Day, Room, Requirement) VALUES ('" & order & "','" & Club & "', '" & Time & "', '" & Day & "', '" & Room & "', '" & Requirement & "');")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub
```

Comment: Never ever use concatenation to glue values into a string for a query.  it is a disaster waiting to happen.  Those interim assignments are also pointless

Comment: Display the created query (e.g. Debug.Print instead of Access.ExecQuery) and check it or put it the question. The rest of your code is probably not relevant. The problem can be an apostrophe in one of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Clubs ([Daysort], [ClubName], [Times], [Day], [Room], [Requirement]) VALUES ('" & order.Text & "','" & Club.Text & "', '" & Time.Text & "', '" & Day.Text & "', '" & Room.Text & "', '" & Requirement.Text & "')")
```